# I want to get the specific data according to its value

Tags: mysql

Example this is my movie table.

[image]

And I'm using this query to get only midway data:

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movie_id = "12" OR movie_id = "18" AND movie_title LIKE "%MIDWAY%" LIMIT 9
```

but unfortunately, it will show two data because of its movie_id, and that's is my problem I only want to get only midway because the movie_id and movie_title is correct.

Comment: I find this hard to believe, since you don't even have a title 'MIDWAY'.

Comment: Its there, can you view the image?

Comment: Sure, very pretty image. I see 'Midway', not 'MIDWAY'.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille We have no idea of the column collation.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing unfortunate about the result, you get what you asked for.  Better brush up on your knowledge of logic, and the notion "precedence" in SQL.

Try the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM movies
  WHERE ( movie_id = "12" OR movie_id = "18" )
    AND movie_title LIKE "%MIDWAY%"
  LIMIT 9
```

I still don't understand how this could return a row with a title 'Midway'.  Perhaps there is a setting that allows MySQL to be case insensitive?

Comment: Isn't MySQL case insensitive by default?

Comment: "Perhaps there is a setting that allows MySQL to be case insensitive" - Collations.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I haven't been to church for a while.  And my eyesight isn't getting any better neither.  Just verified, it really has case insensitive collations, they're even the default.  Thanks for learning me this bad news.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I looking for. I'm  just new to SQL